Week Start Date to start from Monday
I have a Dimdate table where I have dates.
I want week to start from Monday.
My query :
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT
    DATE,
    DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,DATE),0) AS WEEK_START,
    DATENAME(DW,DATE) AS DAY_OF_WEEK
FROM
    DIMDATE

My Output is :



Date
Weekstart
Day Of Week




2024-03-31
2024-04-01
Sunday


2024-04-01
2024-04-01
Monday



The Issue is Previous Sunday's date being considered weekstartDate which has to be from Monday - Sunday
I need



Date
Weekstart
Day Of Week




2024-03-31
2024-03-25
Sunday


2024-04-01
2024-04-01
Monday




Your chances to get a good answer will be better if you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and do what explained

Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

From the manual : Specifying SET DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function operates in a deterministic way.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

CREATE TABLE DIMDATE 
(
    Date    DATE
);

INSERT INTO DIMDATE (Date) VALUES
    ('2024-03-31'),
    ('2024-04-01'),
    ('2024-04-02'),
    ('2024-04-03'),
    ('2024-04-04'),
    ('2024-04-05'),
    ('2024-04-06'),
    ('2024-04-07'),
    ('2024-04-08');

SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT
    DATE,
    DATEADD(day,-(DATEPART(dw,[Date])-1), DATE) AS WEEK_START,
    DATENAME(DW,DATE) AS DAY_OF_WEEK
FROM
    DIMDATE

fiddle



DATE
WEEK_START
DAY_OF_WEEK




2024-03-31
2024-03-25
Sunday


2024-04-01
2024-04-01
Monday


2024-04-02
2024-04-01
Tuesday


2024-04-03
2024-04-01
Wednesday


2024-04-04
2024-04-01
Thursday


2024-04-05
2024-04-01
Friday


2024-04-06
2024-04-01
Saturday


2024-04-07
2024-04-01
Sunday


2024-04-08
2024-04-08
Monday



